# how to increase/decrease font-size from external css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project and having trouble to increase or decrease font size of the site. I am using wordpress, Genesis framework but unable to increase/decrease font size via javascript.

Please kindly help me to solve this.

i use the following code;

**genesis_after Hook
This hook executes immediately before the closing  tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Reset Font Size
  var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  $(".resetFont").click(function(){
  $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });
  // Increase Font Size
  $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
  // Decrease Font Size
  $(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

**genesis_before_content Hook
This hook executes immediately before the content column (outside the #content div).**

```
<a href="#" class="increaseFont">Increase</a>
<a href="#" class="decreaseFont">Decrease</a>
<a href="#" class="resetFont">Reset</a>
```

my project link is

http://174.121.86.229/~rghlifts/

please help me to resolve the issue

thank you all

Comment: You are using mootools and jquery together... if you are doing that... mootools is going to use the "$" operator... you need to add jQuery.noConflict() and change all your "$" to jQuery so that mootools  is free to use "$" since it's not namespaced (ala Prototype)

Comment: @El Guapo please can you tell me... i m not so good with jquery or mootools

Comment: see @Grzegorz Gąsak comment in his answer... he's done it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Wordpress jQuery is default with noConflict. You must change in your script all "$" to "jQuery".

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var fontSizeCookie = getCookie('font_size');
    if (typeof fontSizeCookie !== 'undefined' && fontSizeCookie != null) {
        jQuery('html').css('font-size', fontSizeCookie+'px');
    }

    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = 10;
    jQuery(".resetFont").click(function(){
        jQuery('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
        createCookie('font_size', originalFontSize, 365);
    });
    // Increase Font Size
    jQuery(".increaseFont").click(function(){
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('html').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
        jQuery('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize+'px');
        createCookie('font_size', newFontSize, 365);
        return false;
    });
    // Decrease Font Size
    jQuery(".decreaseFont").click(function(){
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('html').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;
        jQuery('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize);
        createCookie('font_size', newFontSize, 365);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please help me correctify the codes ..

Comment: Can you paste code from file header.php your WP template?

Comment: He's seeing this because he's using Mootools and jQuery together and doesn't have jQuery set to "noConflict".

Comment: well actuually i get these codes from http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/text-resizing-with-jquery/ ...

Comment: In Wordpress jQuery is default with noConflict. You must change in your script all "$" to "jQuery".

Comment: yeah i implement the codes you gave me ... but still not working :( .. can you please check the link http://174.121.86.229/~rghlifts/

Comment: Do you know use of em units in CSS?

Comment: yes i do know, but y u asking

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3217/discussion-between-muzammil-and-grzegorz-gasak)

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);` to `$('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize);`

and also change other occurances of `font-sıze` to `fontSize` too..

Comment: @fenerlitk no, still not working :( please can you check my project website and the codes if possible.

Comment: You don't need to do this.  jQuery understands both methods: `For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') and .css('backgroundColor').`  See this: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: try $('html').css('fontSize', newFontSize+'px');

Answer (score 0):

Are your events being executed (try using Firebug to check), if not..

Instead of using

```
$({classname}).click...
```

try

```
$({classname}).live('click', function(evt){..})
```

See if that works better for you. Could be a timing issue regarding your dom and your JS.

If your events are being run, then there's an issue somewhere else in your code.